# How to write calabash features in a optimized way? Refer me any source to learn?

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I am a newbie of calabash-android. i did learn how to write scripts for automation testing. please refer me some "books" or "articles" to learn how to write scripts in a optimized way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently started a new job as an automated tester for a mobile app and found the following book a good introduction to the Cucumber framework:

https://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book

It doesn't go into lots of detail about Calabash specifically but does have lots of information on writing tests in general.

Once you have your feature files in place you just write the underlying code (Ruby in my case) to make the app do what you want (ie. touch, swipe).

It's also good to use:
query('*') whilst in the calabash-android console. It dumps out the all the information you need to know for example what ID's and text to check for on any given screen.

Comment: Thank you @Woodi2391. Give me some suggestion whether automation has future career scope or not?